# Access a varray type defined inside a package using oci_new_collection

Tags: php, oracle, package, oracle-call-interface, varray

Hello I am trying to pass in varrays from PHP  to Oracle. I am using OCI8 and have earlier worked with varrays as arguments in stored procedures, and on compilation the types of those varrays are created. So while making collection instance on the PHP end, we can directly mention the collection name.

Ex:

```
$my_coll = oci_new_collection($c, 'MY_ARRAY');
```

where MY_ARRAY would be the varray type I had declared in the Oracle instance.

```
create or replace type MY_ARRAY as varray(100) of varchar2(20);
```

So when I create them outside a package, the type is compiled and would be ready during execution.

If I do that from packages, I am getting back the error

**PHP Warning:  oci_new_collection() [function.oci-new-collection]: OCI-22303: type ""."my_pack.my_array_type" not found**

My package header would look like this

```
create or replace
PACKAGE my_pack
AS
   TYPE my_array_type is VARRAY(200) of varchar2(20);
    my_arr my_array_type;

    function my_func(
    in_id number,
    in_arr my_array_type    
    )
    return number;

end my_pack;
```

Now when I make a call from PHP to create an instance of collection, this is the way I do

```
$my_collection = oci_new_collection($connect,'my_pack.my_array_type');
```

Now I get the warning type not found.

My question is, how would I have to call the varray type that is in the package??? I am doing it as package.type_name, but I am getting the warning that says type not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to pass schema and typename in uppercase

```
oci_new_collection($connect,'MY_PACK.MY_ARRAY_TYPE', 'MY_SCHEMA')
```

**Upd.**

I've found no limitations in OCI Reference, but PL\SQL Reference was more informative:

> A PL/SQL composite type defined in a
>   package specification is incompatible
>   with an identically defined local or
>   standalone stored type

Also from PL\SQL Reference (Table 5-1) all sorts of collections have restrictions. For example VARRAY declared at package level:

> Can Be ADT Attribute Data Type only if
>   defined at schema level

Comment: done that, tried passing schema in upper and typename in lowercase too, but it still gives me the  same error

Comment: well the schema would be mentioned only if the package and type do not exist in that schema. In this case, they do. :(

Comment: So looks like there's no way to do this without schema-level definition

Comment: Yes, seems so, do you have any idea of how to pass a date from php to a package expecting dates in oracle?

Comment: some variants at first blush: using of CLOB with parsing on db size, SYS_REFCURSOR as input param in package function and array to refcursor PL/SQL implementation, and, in the last, using of ANYDATA

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
$in_arr = array('1','2','3');    
$s = ociparse($database, "BEGIN my_pack.my_func(:in_id, :in_arr); END;");
oci_bind_by_name($s, ':in_id', $in_id, 32 );
oci_bind_array_by_name($s, ':in_arr', $in_arr, 250, -1, SQLT_VCS);
```

If you need out:

```
$out_arr = array(); //OUT   
$s = ociparse($database, "BEGIN my_pack.my_func(:in_id, :out_arr); END;") ;
oci_bind_by_name($s, ':in_id', $in_id, 32);
oci_bind_array_by_name($s,':out_arr', $out_arr, 250, 250, SQLT_VCS);
                                                     // change -1 for 250
```